# root node slash vs root node name

Tags: xml, xslt

Why would the slash cause a file io error (cannot open xml file) vs if I specifically use name in match it works? Aren't they synonymous?

snippet of code below:

```
  <xsl:template match="/"> <!-- In question, different results / vs root -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Sample xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"> <!-- In question, different results / vs root -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="greeting">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="helloworld.xslt"?>
<root>
  <greeting>
    Hello, World!
  </greeting>
  <greeting>
    Hello, World Too!
  </greeting>
</root>
```

Comment: the `root` element is a child of `/`

Comment: can you please provide a little more insight? why does it throw an exception when I use the slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `/` you are at the document level.

The only element that exists on the document level is the `<root>` element. But you are using the `select` attribute to say, specifically apply templates to the element named greetings, but this does not exist on the document level, it exists in your `<root>` element.

You have three options.

1. Change it to `<xsl:template match="/root">`
2. Remove the select `<xsl:apply-templates />`
3. Change your select to `<xsl:apply-templates select="root/greeting"/>`